# merge various components using itextsharp to create a pdf in c#

Tags: c#, itext

I have a panel in c# which contains various components like picture boxes and a datagridview.
I wish to create a pdf which includes the whole datagridview and the picture boxes together.
For now, only datagridview or picture boxes appear in the pdf. Merging both together is not being possible. I am using iTextSharp for pdf creation.
My code is as below..

```
        string strFileName;

        string FontPath = "C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\simsun.ttc,1";

        int FontSize = 12;

        ///

        Boolean cc = false;
        SaveFileDialog savFile = new SaveFileDialog();
        savFile.AddExtension = true;
        savFile.DefaultExt = "pdf";
        savFile.Filter = "PDF Document|*.pdf|*.pdf|";

        savFile.ShowDialog();

        if (savFile.FileName != "")
        {
            strFileName = savFile.FileName;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("export stop", "export stop", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            return;
        }


        iTextSharp.text.Image jpg= iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Properties.Resources.templete3, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        jpg.ScaleToFit(750, 850);
        jpg.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);

        // Page site and margin left, right, top, bottom is defined
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);//, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);


        //If you want to choose image as background then,



        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create));

        BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(FontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

        iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(baseFont, FontSize);

        pdfDoc.Open();

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count);


        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(datagridview[j, 0].Value.ToString(), font));
        }

        table.HeaderRows = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                try
                {
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[j, i].Value.ToString(), font));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    cc = true;
                }
            }
        }


        pdfDoc.NewPage();

        pdfDoc.Add(jpg);

        pdfDoc.Add(table);
        pdfDoc.Close();

        Process.Start(strFileName);

     }


}
```

Comment: Is the panel / datagrid / image used in an asp.net application? If so,  you might be able to render them as HTML and convert that. Unrelated to the issue, I think it's cute how you name your png as `jpg`.

Comment: @Nenotlep: No unfortunately we are using c# language. Is there any other way to do it using c#

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer (yet). Your code appears to be a part of a larger project and there's a lot of extraneous code not related to the specific problem. The first step in diagnosing something like this is to remove everything that's not essential so that we can actually reproduce your problem. Below is an attempt at doing that.

The code first creates a sample environment based on what you've told us. First it creates some sample data and adds that to a `DataGridView`. Then it loads an existing image into a `PictureBox`. Then it adds these two controls to a newly created `Panel`. After those steps, it creates a PDF, gets the image from the `PictureBox`, gets the data from the table and adds all of those to the PDF. See the comments in the code for more details. When I run this code I get both a table and an image in my PDF.

If you run this code, **START IN A BRAND NEW PROJECT - DO NOT USE YOUR EXISTING PROJECT**. I can't stress that enough. Do not pick parts of this code to run, start a fresh project and use this and only this for your code. If this works then hopefully you can start comparing differences between the working code and the non-working code.

This code was tested in VS Express 2012 For Windows Desktop against iTextSharp 5.4.0.

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication20 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //Used for our sample data
        public class Person {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            //Sample image, set to a PNG
            var sampleImagePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "sample.png");
            //Full path to the PDF to export
            var exportFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Test.pdf");

            //Next we're going to create all of the basic controls per the OP's scenario

            //Create some sample data to put into our DGV
            var P1 = new Person() { FirstName = "Alice", LastName = "Cooper" };
            var P2 = new Person() { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Dole" };
            var People = new List<Person>(new Person[] { P1, P2 });

            //Create our sample DataGridView
            var dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = People;
            dataGridView1.Location = new Point(0, 0);

            //Create our sample PictureBox
            var PB = new PictureBox();
            PB.Load(sampleImagePath);
            PB.Location = new Point(400, 0);
            PB.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;


            //Create our sample panel and give it room to show everything
            var panel = new Panel();
            panel.AutoSize = true;
            panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            //Add the above controls to our DGV
            panel.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
            panel.Controls.Add(PB);
            //Add the DGV to the form
            this.Controls.Add(panel);

            //Basic PDF creation here, nothing special
            using (var fs = new FileStream(exportFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
                using (var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4)) {
                    using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, fs)) {
                        pdfDoc.Open();

                        //Get our image (Code is mostly the OP's)
                        iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(PB.Image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        jpg.ScaleToFit(750, 850);
                        jpg.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);

                        //Create our table
                        var table = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count);

                        //Add the headers from the DGV to the table
                        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++) {
                            table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText));
                        }

                        //Flag the first row as a header
                        table.HeaderRows = 1;

                        //Add the actual rows from the DGV to the table
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++) {
                                table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[j, i].Value.ToString()));
                            }
                        }

                        //Add our image
                        pdfDoc.Add(jpg);
                        //Add out table
                        pdfDoc.Add(table);
                        pdfDoc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```